# Rails Model Validation in abstract base class that needs to utilize name of child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, json-schema-validator

I'm doing a rails setup with Single Table Inheritance, where each class has all of it's attributes stored on a JSON blob, the structure of which is defined in a json schema file unique to that class.

I want to run validations on each class against its json schema but the logic is the same for every class minus the path to the schema itself which depends on the name of the STI class and the sub class.

This setup relies on the gem 'activerecord_json_validator' which specifies a format for the validation schema files and some helpers for validation

So the desired setup is something like

`/app/models/data_generating_module` (the abstract STI base class which is never instantiated)

```rb
class DataGeneratingModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :action_coordinates

  def self.schema_path
    "#{Rails.root}/app/models/json_schemas/#{superclass.to_s.underscore}/#{self.to_s.underscore}.json"
  end

  validates :module_data, presence: true, json:  { message: ->(errors) { errors },  schema: self.schema_path }
end
```

app/models/sub_sti (the class that get's instantiated)

```rb
class SubSti< DataGeneratingModule
end
```

`schema_path` should evaluate to `repo/app/models/json_schemas/data_generating_module/sub_sti.json"`

If I leave the `schema_path` and validation code on the sub class it all works.

after doing this, `SubSti` can be instanciated but if I call `.valid?` on it it throws an error because when `schema_path` get's called it's using the values for the superclass not the subclass.

```
JSON::Schema::ReadFailed (Read of file at /git/repo/app/models/json_schemas/active_record/base/data_generating_module.json failed)
```

So basically how can I move all of this data to the abstract STI class to avoid duplicating it but where it still interpolates the proper values from the child class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting this inside an inherited hook and then class evaling inside of the subclass got this working:

```rb
class DataGeneratingModule < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.inherited(subclass)
      subclass.class_eval do
        validates :module_data, presence: true, json:  { message: ->(errors) { errors },  schema: "#{Rails.root}/app/models/json_schemas/#{subclass.superclass.to_s.underscore}/#{subclass.to_s.underscore.split("/").last}.json" }
      end

      super
    end
end
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, you mentioned this is an abstract base class but your ABC isn't using self.abstract_class = true, mine is which is one reason it may not be working. In my case I have to explicitly make the class abstract so a model isn't generated for it. This guy (https://medium.com/@jeremy_96642/deep-rails-how-to-use-abstract-classes-6aee9b686e75) also has an example of doing this with an explicit abstract base class. Although this also did not work for me...